# Deleted couchbase document seems visible to update but not get

Tags: memcached, couchbase

When trying to update a couchbase document that was previously deleted the update call fails with a CASResponse.EXISTS code rather than a CASResponse.NOT_FOUND. However a call to get the previously deleted key immediately after the delete is complete returns null as expected:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
  val uris = List(URI.create("http://localhost:8091/pools"))

  val client = new CouchbaseClient(uris, "test", "password")  

  client.add("asdf", "qwer").get

  client.delete("asdf").get

  val result = client.asyncGets("asdf").get

  assert(result == null)

  val response = client.asyncCAS("asdf", 1, "bar").get

  response match {
    case CASResponse.NOT_FOUND => println("Document Not Found")
    case CASResponse.EXISTS => println("Document exists")
  }
}
```

Adding Thread.sleep(1000) before the update call fixes the problem, so my question is this  the expected behaviour of Couchbase?

Couchbase version is 2.2.0 enterprise edition (build-821), using the Java client version 1.2.1 in Scala 2.10.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably want to do:

```
client.delete(key, PersistTo.MASTER).get();
```

You can change the enum PersistTo to other options such as ONE,TWO,THREE (i.e. Master plus additional numbers of nodes).  I tested your example with only one node and the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use **client.gets()** instead of **client.asyncGets().get()** and **client.cas()** instead of **client.asyncCAS().get()**? I think it can solve your problem.